# Specifying exceptions to Rails Filters (aka Action Callbacks) by controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Following https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters, I have a method `pull_alerts` which I need to run before a number of actions. Those actions are in a few different controllers so I have the code in **application_controller.rb**:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :pull_alerts, only: [:home, :profile, :show, :new]

  private

    def pull_alerts
      @unread_notifications = <... some code here ...>
    end

end
```

This works well, with `home` and `profile` being the names of two actions in **pages_controller.rb** and `show` and `new` being the names of two actions in **widget_controller.rb**.

I now want have `pull_alerts` run before the `show` action in a third controller - eg. **doodad_controller.rb** - but *not* before the `new` action in that controller. I have been unable to find a reference to how to specify this (namespace / scope?) in the condition:

```
before_action :pull_alerts, only: [:home, :profile, :show, :new]
```

What's the best way to structure this arrangement? Do I need to move this out of **application_controller.rb** and specify the `before_action` in each separate controller (pages, widgets, doodads)? If I do that, where can I put the method so that it's DRY? Or would it better to add this in **doodad_controller.rb** like this?

```
class DoodadsController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :pull_alerts, only: [:new]

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer depends on what you want to trade off against what.

### Trade offs

In this case there are a few things to consider:

- Readability / Understandability
- Duplication
- Number of lines of code
- Extensibility

What do you value most highly?

### My perspective

Personally, I value readability more highly than most other things - including duplication.

In my experience it's very easy to get obsessed with DRY and end up with code that confuses you in three months.

### Solution

```ruby
# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def pull_alerts
    @unread_notifications = <... some code here ...>
  end
end

# home_controller.rb
class HomeController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :pull_alerts, only: [:show, :new]
end

# profile_controller.rb
class ProfileController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :pull_alerts, only: [:show, :new]
end

# doodad_controller.rb
class DoodadController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :pull_alerts, only: :show
end
```

Sure, it's got some duplication. But if you read the code you can tell in seconds what's going on.

### In contrast

This code:

```ruby
class DoodadsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :pull_alerts, only: :new
end
```

requires that you look at what actions `pull_alerts` is called before. Then you need to think in the "negative" - i.e. which is skipped.

Another drawback here is extensibility - if you want to call `pull_alerts` before `:update` too, it starts to get messy to know whether pull_alerts is still called on update in `DoodadsController`

Comment: Thanks, John. I appreciate the time you took to put this answer together.